# How to fix "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound''"

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault, .net-5, asp.net5

I am trying to get the values from my Azure Key vault in ASP.net 5 Web API application. But faced with this issue.

[image]

I have added this code in Program.cs file

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            var builtConfig = config.Build();
            var vaultName = builtConfig["keyvault"];

            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                async (authoriy, resource, scope) =>
                {
                    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(false);
                    var token = credential.GetToken(
                            new TokenRequestContext(
                                new[] {"https://vault.azure.net/.default" }
                                )
                        );
                    return token.Token;
                });
            config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                vaultName,
                keyVaultClient,
                new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
        });
```

In appsettings.json file, I gave the key-vault URL like this.

```
"Keyvault": "https://<<vaultName>>.vault.azure.net/.default"
```

And I have created the Secret with the name "StorageConnectionString" I am using in my Class in the Azure Key-vault.

```
public BlobContainerProvider(IConfiguration configuration) 
    {
        
        string connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("StorageConnectionString");

        blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check if any of these helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124843/keyvaulterrorexception-operation-returned-an-invalid-status-code-forbidden

Comment: @Sajeetharan unfortunately, none of these answers worked for me. I had already looked upon these answers before posting my question. But no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you have a secret with nae `StorageConnectionString` in key vault ?

Comment: Out of interest where is this being hosted? IE AWS, Azure app service, Private cloud etc

Comment: @Thomas, Yes I have that connectionString in the Keyvault.

Comment: @blockingHD, This will be hosted in Azure Appservice.

Comment: I would be tempted to for go the direct implementation and use [Key Vault References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) - Note this isn't an answer but a suggestion for another solution.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `"EventStoreKeyvault": "https://<<vaultName>>.vault.azure.net/.default"`?

Comment: @blockingHD, Yea that's a good suggestion. But it is not compliant with Managed Identities.

Comment: @GauravMantri, '.default' was added by mistake, removing it from the question.

Comment: var vaultName = builtConfig["keyvault"]; why do you have this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include your appSettings.json file? Please obfuscate the name of the resources. I am interested in seeing the value of `keyvault` setting in your appSettings.json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue, It is actually in appsettings.json

I have mentioned it as

```
"Keyvault": "https://<<vaultName>>.vault.azure.net/.default"
```

Whereas ".default" in the URL should not be placed.

So Generally, such a type of error is thrown if we have placed an unavailable key-vault URL.

@Gaurav Mantri, Thanks for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: Great! I am glad to hear that your issue has been resolved.